# Angular 5 using FormGroup inside a custom FormControl

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I am trying to create a custom FormControl using the `ControlValueAccessor` interface. My aim is to get back an object like below from the custom FormControl in the parent form (example):

```
{
  prop1: int,
  prop2: string,
  prop3: { prop31: int, prop32: string, prop33: int }
}
```

**My custom Form Control** (decorator omitted for brevity):

```
export class MyCustomControlComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

    private _value: any
    form: FormGroup

    set value(value: any) {
        this._value = value
        this.notifyValueChange()
    }

    get value() { return this._value }

    onChange: (value) => {}
    onTouched: () => {}

    constructor(
        public fb: FormBuilder,
    ) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            prop1: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.min(0)])],
            prop2: [null, Validators.required],
            prop3: this.fb.group({
                prop31: [null, Validators.required],
                prop32: [null, Validators.required],
                prop33: [null, Validators.required],
            }),
        })
    }

    setValues() {
        const formValues = this.form.value
        this.writeValue(formValues)
    }

    notifyValueChange() {
        if (this.onChange) {
            this.onChange(this.value)
        }
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(_ => this.setValues())
    }

    writeValue(obj: any): void { this.value = obj }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void { this.onChange = fn }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void { this.onTouched = fn }
    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void { }
}
```

**Parent form:**

```
childForm: FormControl
constructor(...) {
  childForm = new FormControl()
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.childForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log(value))
}
```

With this in parent form, I get the values from the custom form control. But once I try to set some initial values from parent form, none of them appears inside the custom form. My understanding is that I need to map the object that I receive from parent inside custom control's inner `FormGroup` but I am not sure where and how. Help will be appreciated. Also, opinion on better approaches (if any) for this are welcome.

**EDIT**

To answer why I am trying to achieve this: I have a very large form and a part which is involved with this sample object given above, is actually dynamic - meaning I need to store array of such objects at the end. To free some clutter, I am trying to move this part into a single form control so that I can use a `FormArray` to handle this.

Comment: A form control is the end of the form : it's a control. Why would you put a group of controls in it ? It should be the opposite : you create a form group and append form controls to it. Is there a particular use case for that behavior ? If so, maybe you should explain it in your question.

Comment: @trichetriche I have updated my question. Hope you find the answer useful. Also if you have some suggestion on how such complexity should be handled, please share. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you have solved your problem if still, you are looking for a good solution, then please let me know, I will share some information on this.